# Can multiple verbs be used together, like in "kids cry, yell and misbehave"?

Tags: verbs

Can 3 verbs be used together as in the below example?

> Kids **cry, yell and misbehave** when their father is not at home.

I know that the example is a bit dumb so don't pay too much attention to its meaning.

Comment: As a general principle you can have any number of consecutive verbs (possibly separated by conjunctions such as ***and / or***) in English. What makes you think your example *might* not be valid?

Comment: I feel that it might not be valid because the sentence structure that I was taught with subject+predicate usually has just one verb. Also, English seems particularly fond of short & simple sentences as opposed to French or German where sentences can go on over many lines.

Comment: Well, you obviously don't see any problem with multiple consecutive ***nouns*** (***French*** or ***German***), and ***adjectives*** (***short*** & ***simple*** sentences). Verbs are no different.

Comment: I have seen many adjective lists in English. However, I have never seen it with verbs, thus the question.

Comment: Think of them as coordinated (with _and_). English allows all but the last _and_ to be omitted, but it still behaves as a coordination. This is different from a list of adjectives, which _can_ be coordinated, but can also be concatenated without coordination.

Answer (score 0):

There is the famous Latin phrase: Veni, vidi, vici ("I came, I saw, I conquered) that is three verbs with the subject embedded in the conjugations. I assume that stringing multiple verbs should be possible (I am not a linguist) in any language.

As an example:

*All cities rise, thrive, stagnate and (eventually) fall.*

There are a million examples I could write of multiple actions (verbs) being strung together consecutively.

Note that in modern English writing, a conjunction (and) is not required between consecutive words, although it could be used. For example:

*Red, white and blue bunting decorated the stage.
Red and white and blue beams of light shone throughout the room.*

*She ran and jumped and hopped and skipped across the playground.*

*She ran, jumped, hopped and skipped across the playground.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they can. Why would you doubt that?

Almost separately, why would you ask us not to pay attention to the meaning?

What would be lost if you dropped '… when their father is not at home' to concentrate on 'Kids cry… etc'?